# Set variable date value with moment.js

Tags: jquery, datatables, datepicker, momentjs

I am using [this example](https://datatables.net/extensions/datetime/examples/integration/datatables.html) of datatables using a date range picker.

I would like to remove the date picker and just set the start and end date variable values when the table loads. I have tried to no avail. The closest I could get was by pre setting the minimum and maximum date range input fields values like this:

```
$.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
    function( settings, data, dataIndex ) {
        var min = minDate.val();
        var max = maxDate.val();
        var date = new Date( data[0] );
 
        if (
            ( min === null && max === null ) ||
            ( min === null && date <= max ) ||
            ( min <= date   && max === null ) ||
            ( min <= date   && date <= max )
        ) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
);
```

and:

```
minDate = new DateTime($('#min'), {
    format: 'YYYY-MM-DD'
});
maxDate = new DateTime($('#max'), {
    format: 'YYYY-MM-DD'
});

$("#max").val(moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
$("#min").val(moment().subtract(7, 'd').format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
```

My goal is to remove these two input fields and instead set the 'min' and 'max' variables to the above values.

I have set up a [jsfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/bsv7jLcw/3/). Can anyone lend a hand? Thanks :)

Comment: What do you mean by 'to the above values'?

Comment: @0stone0referring to the #max #min values he created which will always represent current day and 7 days before the current day

Answer (score 0):

Here, you can just apply a CSS styling to the first table including those `#min` `#max` values and they will still read the input being inserted with the JavaScript.

I applied the id `#maxmin` to the first table which includes the two date ranges. Then in the CSS I was able to call that ID and set it to `display: none;`

```js
var minDate, maxDate;
 
// Custom filtering function which will search data in column four between two values
$.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
    function( settings, data, dataIndex ) {
        var min = minDate.val();
        var max = maxDate.val();
        var date = new Date( data[0] );
 
        if (
            ( min === null && max === null ) ||
            ( min === null && date <= max ) ||
            ( min <= date   && max === null ) ||
            ( min <= date   && date <= max )
        ) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
);
 
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Create date inputs
    minDate = new DateTime($('#min'), {
        format: 'YYYY-MM-DD'
    });
    maxDate = new DateTime($('#max'), {
        format: 'YYYY-MM-DD'
    });
    
$("#max").val(moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
    $("#min").val(moment().subtract(7, 'd').format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
       
    // DataTables initialisation
    var table = $('#chart_data').DataTable();
    
    table.draw();
 
    // Refilter the table
    $('#min, #max').on('change', function () {
        table.draw();
    });
});
```

```css
#maxmin{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.25/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/datetime/1.1.0/css/dataTables.dateTime.min.css">
  
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.25/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/datetime/1.1.0/js/dataTables.dateTime.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table border="0" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5" id="maxmin">
        <tbody><tr>
            <td>Minimum date:</td>
            <td><input type="text" id="min" name="min"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Maximum date:</td>
            <td><input type="text" id="max" name="max"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody></table>
    
    <table id="chart_data">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Count</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
<tr>
    <td>2021-08-04</td>
    <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2021-08-03</td>
    <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2021-08-02</td>
    <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2021-07-29</td>
    <td>2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2021-07-28</td>
    <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2021-07-27</td>
    <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2021-07-26</td>
    <td>2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2021-07-23</td>
    <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2021-07-22</td>
    <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2021-07-21</td>
    <td>4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2021-07-20</td>
    <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2021-07-19</td>
    <td>5</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2021-07-16</td>
    <td>3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2021-07-15</td>
    <td>5</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2021-07-14</td>
    <td>2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2021-07-13</td>
    <td>8</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2021-07-12</td>
    <td>5</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2021-07-09</td>
    <td>8</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2021-07-08</td>
    <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2021-07-07</td>
    <td>3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2021-07-06</td>
    <td>2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2021-07-05</td>
    <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2021-06-28</td>
    <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2021-06-25</td>
    <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2021-06-24</td>
    <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2021-06-23</td>
    <td>2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2021-06-22</td>
    <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2021-06-21</td>
    <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2021-06-17</td>
    <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2021-06-16</td>
    <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2021-06-15</td>
    <td>2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2021-06-14</td>
    <td>3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2021-06-09</td>
    <td>2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2021-06-07</td>
    <td>2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2021-06-04</td>
    <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2021-06-03</td>
    <td>4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2021-06-02</td>
    <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2021-06-01</td>
    <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2021-05-27</td>
    <td>2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2021-05-25</td>
    <td>2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2021-05-24</td>
    <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2021-05-21</td>
    <td>2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2021-05-20</td>
    <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2021-05-18</td>
    <td>2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2021-05-17</td>
    <td>4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2021-05-13</td>
    <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2021-05-12</td>
    <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2021-05-11</td>
    <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2021-05-10</td>
    <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2021-05-07</td>
    <td>2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2021-05-06</td>
    <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2021-05-04</td>
    <td>2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2021-04-30</td>
    <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2021-04-29</td>
    <td>2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2021-04-28</td>
    <td>3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2021-04-27</td>
    <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2021-04-22</td>
    <td>3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2021-04-21</td>
    <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2021-04-20</td>
    <td>4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2021-04-19</td>
    <td>3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2021-04-15</td>
    <td>2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2021-04-13</td>
    <td>2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2021-03-31</td>
    <td>2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2021-03-30</td>
    <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2021-03-29</td>
    <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2021-03-26</td>
    <td>4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2021-03-24</td>
    <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2021-03-23</td>
    <td>4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2021-03-22</td>
    <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2021-03-19</td>
    <td>3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2021-03-18</td>
    <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2021-03-17</td>
    <td>2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2021-03-15</td>
    <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2021-03-12</td>
    <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2021-03-11</td>
    <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2021-03-10</td>
    <td>3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2021-03-09</td>
    <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2021-03-08</td>
    <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2021-03-05</td>
    <td>3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2021-03-04</td>
    <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2021-03-03</td>
    <td>2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2021-03-02</td>
    <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2021-03-01</td>
    <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2021-02-26</td>
    <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2021-02-25</td>
    <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2021-02-24</td>
    <td>2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2021-02-23</td>
    <td>4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2021-02-22</td>
    <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2021-02-19</td>
    <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2021-02-18</td>
    <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2021-02-17</td>
    <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2021-02-16</td>
    <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2021-02-12</td>
    <td>2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2021-02-11</td>
    <td>3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2021-02-10</td>
    <td>2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2021-02-09</td>
    <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2021-02-05</td>
    <td>5</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2021-02-04</td>
    <td>3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2021-02-03</td>
    <td>12</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2021-02-01</td>
    <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2021-01-29</td>
    <td>3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2021-01-28</td>
    <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2021-01-27</td>
    <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2021-01-25</td>
    <td>3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2021-01-22</td>
    <td>3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2021-01-21</td>
    <td>6</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2021-01-20</td>
    <td>2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2021-01-19</td>
    <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2021-01-18</td>
    <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2021-01-14</td>
    <td>2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2021-01-13</td>
    <td>2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2021-01-07</td>
    <td>3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2021-01-06</td>
    <td>2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2020-12-23</td>
    <td>6</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2020-12-21</td>
    <td>4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2020-12-18</td>
    <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2020-12-16</td>
    <td>2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2020-12-15</td>
    <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2020-12-14</td>
    <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2020-12-13</td>
    <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2020-12-08</td>
    <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2020-12-07</td>
    <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2020-12-04</td>
    <td>18</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2020-12-03</td>
    <td>6</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2020-12-02</td>
    <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2020-12-01</td>
    <td>4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2020-11-30</td>
    <td>4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2020-11-24</td>
    <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2020-11-23</td>
    <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2020-11-19</td>
    <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2020-11-18</td>
    <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2020-11-16</td>
    <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2020-11-13</td>
    <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2020-11-12</td>
    <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2020-11-10</td>
    <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2020-11-09</td>
    <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2020-11-06</td>
    <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2020-11-05</td>
    <td>3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2020-11-04</td>
    <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2020-10-28</td>
    <td>2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2020-10-27</td>
    <td>2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2020-10-26</td>
    <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2020-10-23</td>
    <td>3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2020-10-22</td>
    <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2020-10-21</td>
    <td>5</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2020-10-20</td>
    <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2020-10-14</td>
    <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2020-10-09</td>
    <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2020-10-08</td>
    <td>3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2020-10-07</td>
    <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2020-10-01</td>
    <td>3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2020-09-30</td>
    <td>2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2020-09-25</td>
    <td>2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2020-09-24</td>
    <td>6</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2020-09-23</td>
    <td>4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2020-09-21</td>
    <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2020-09-18</td>
    <td>2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2020-09-17</td>
    <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2020-09-16</td>
    <td>6</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2020-09-15</td>
    <td>2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2020-09-14</td>
    <td>3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2020-09-11</td>
    <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2020-09-10</td>
    <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2020-09-09</td>
    <td>2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2020-09-08</td>
    <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2020-09-04</td>
    <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2020-09-03</td>
    <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2020-09-01</td>
    <td>3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2020-08-31</td>
    <td>5</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2020-08-28</td>
    <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2020-08-27</td>
    <td>3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2020-08-26</td>
    <td>8</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2020-08-25</td>
    <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2020-08-24</td>
    <td>6</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2020-08-21</td>
    <td>5</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2020-08-20</td>
    <td>5</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2020-08-19</td>
    <td>4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2020-08-17</td>
    <td>12</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2020-08-13</td>
    <td>2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2020-08-12</td>
    <td>3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2020-08-11</td>
    <td>12</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2020-08-10</td>
    <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2020-08-06</td>
    <td>4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2020-08-04</td>
    <td>2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2020-08-03</td>
    <td>2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2020-07-31</td>
    <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2020-07-27</td>
    <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2020-07-20</td>
    <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2020-07-15</td>
    <td>2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2020-07-14</td>
    <td>2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2020-07-13</td>
    <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2020-07-09</td>
    <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2020-07-03</td>
    <td>2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2020-07-01</td>
    <td>5</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2020-06-30</td>
    <td>4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2020-06-23</td>
    <td>2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2020-06-19</td>
    <td>2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2020-06-18</td>
    <td>4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2020-06-16</td>
    <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2020-06-15</td>
    <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2020-06-11</td>
    <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2020-06-10</td>
    <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2020-06-05</td>
    <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2020-06-04</td>
    <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2020-05-29</td>
    <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2020-05-26</td>
    <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2020-05-25</td>
    <td>2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2020-05-21</td>
    <td>2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2020-05-20</td>
    <td>2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2020-05-15</td>
    <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2020-05-14</td>
    <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2020-05-11</td>
    <td>6</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2020-05-09</td>
    <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2020-05-08</td>
    <td>9</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2020-05-07</td>
    <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2020-05-06</td>
    <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2020-05-05</td>
    <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2020-05-03</td>
    <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2020-04-30</td>
    <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2020-04-29</td>
    <td>8</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2020-04-28</td>
    <td>3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2020-04-22</td>
    <td>2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2020-04-21</td>
    <td>2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2020-04-20</td>
    <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2020-04-16</td>
    <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2020-04-15</td>
    <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2020-04-14</td>
    <td>2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2020-04-09</td>
    <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2020-04-07</td>
    <td>3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2020-04-06</td>
    <td>3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2020-04-02</td>
    <td>3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2020-04-01</td>
    <td>5</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2020-03-30</td>
    <td>2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2020-03-27</td>
    <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2020-03-26</td>
    <td>2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2020-03-23</td>
    <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2020-03-19</td>
    <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2020-03-18</td>
    <td>2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2020-03-17</td>
    <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2020-03-16</td>
    <td>2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2020-03-13</td>
    <td>3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2020-03-10</td>
    <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2020-03-09</td>
    <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2020-03-06</td>
    <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2020-03-04</td>
    <td>3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2020-03-02</td>
    <td>2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2020-02-28</td>
    <td>3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2020-02-27</td>
    <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2020-02-26</td>
    <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2020-02-20</td>
    <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2020-02-19</td>
    <td>8</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2020-02-18</td>
    <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2020-02-14</td>
    <td>2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2020-02-13</td>
    <td>2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2020-02-12</td>
    <td>3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2020-02-11</td>
    <td>7</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2020-02-10</td>
    <td>14</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2020-02-07</td>
    <td>2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2020-02-06</td>
    <td>3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2020-02-05</td>
    <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2020-02-04</td>
    <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2020-02-03</td>
    <td>10</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2020-01-31</td>
    <td>3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2020-01-30</td>
    <td>2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2020-01-28</td>
    <td>3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2020-01-24</td>
    <td>3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2020-01-23</td>
    <td>14</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2020-01-22</td>
    <td>3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2020-01-21</td>
    <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2020-01-20</td>
    <td>2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2020-01-17</td>
    <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2020-01-16</td>
    <td>3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2020-01-14</td>
    <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2020-01-09</td>
    <td>5</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2020-01-06</td>
    <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2020-01-03</td>
    <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2019-12-19</td>
    <td>2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2019-12-18</td>
    <td>2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2019-12-17</td>
    <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2019-12-16</td>
    <td>3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2019-12-11</td>
    <td>2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2019-12-10</td>
    <td>3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2019-12-09</td>
    <td>11</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2019-12-06</td>
    <td>3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2019-12-03</td>
    <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2019-12-02</td>
    <td>4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2019-11-29</td>
    <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2019-11-28</td>
    <td>2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2019-11-22</td>
    <td>2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2019-11-14</td>
    <td>2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2019-11-07</td>
    <td>3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2019-11-06</td>
    <td>26</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2019-11-04</td>
    <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2019-11-01</td>
    <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2019-10-31</td>
    <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2019-10-23</td>
    <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2019-10-22</td>
    <td>2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2019-10-21</td>
    <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2019-10-17</td>
    <td>2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2019-10-09</td>
    <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2019-10-08</td>
    <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2019-10-04</td>
    <td>2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2019-10-03</td>
    <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2019-09-19</td>
    <td>2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2019-09-16</td>
    <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2019-09-12</td>
    <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2019-09-10</td>
    <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2019-09-06</td>
    <td>3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2019-09-05</td>
    <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2019-09-04</td>
    <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2019-09-03</td>
    <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2019-09-02</td>
    <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2019-08-29</td>
    <td>2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2019-08-26</td>
    <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2019-08-22</td>
    <td>2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2019-08-21</td>
    <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2019-08-16</td>
    <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2019-08-13</td>
    <td>2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2019-08-06</td>
    <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2019-08-01</td>
    <td>2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2019-07-31</td>
    <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2019-07-30</td>
    <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2019-07-29</td>
    <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2019-07-26</td>
    <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2019-07-22</td>
    <td>3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2019-07-17</td>
    <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2019-07-15</td>
    <td>2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2019-07-12</td>
    <td>2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2019-07-11</td>
    <td>3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2019-07-10</td>
    <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2019-06-27</td>
    <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2019-06-11</td>
    <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2019-06-10</td>
    <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2019-06-04</td>
    <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2019-05-29</td>
    <td>4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2019-05-28</td>
    <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2019-05-24</td>
    <td>4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2019-05-23</td>
    <td>2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2019-05-21</td>
    <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2019-05-15</td>
    <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2019-05-08</td>
    <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2019-05-07</td>
    <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2019-05-03</td>
    <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2019-05-02</td>
    <td>2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2019-05-01</td>
    <td>5</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2019-04-30</td>
    <td>13</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2019-04-29</td>
    <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2019-04-24</td>
    <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2019-04-23</td>
    <td>3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2019-04-17</td>
    <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2019-04-10</td>
    <td>2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2019-04-09</td>
    <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2019-04-05</td>
    <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2019-04-04</td>
    <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2019-04-03</td>
    <td>2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2019-04-02</td>
    <td>2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2019-04-01</td>
    <td>2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2019-03-29</td>
    <td>8</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2019-03-28</td>
    <td>3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2019-03-27</td>
    <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2019-03-26</td>
    <td>2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2019-03-25</td>
    <td>5</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2019-03-22</td>
    <td>3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2019-03-20</td>
    <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2019-03-19</td>
    <td>2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2019-03-18</td>
    <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2019-03-15</td>
    <td>1</td>
</tr>

    </tbody>
</table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: but what if his uncle forbids the practice of css?